# Need to split the Java String into two arrays

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I have a String of the following kind in Java. The idea is that the string will contain a list of numbers followed by'Y-' or 'N-'. They may be of any length. I need to extract the list of numbers into two, separately.

```
String str = "Y-1,2,3,4N-5,6,7,8" 
//Other examples: "Y-1N-3,6,5" or "Y-1,2,9,18N-36"
```

I need to break it down into the following arrays:

```
arr1[] = {1,2,3,4}
arr2[] = {5,6,7,8}
```

How do I do it?

Comment: What is the rationale for that string producing those arrays?

Comment: Have you tried .substring() then .split() works like a charm

Comment: I just need the set of (comma delimited) numbers after the characters 'Y-' and 'N-' separately. 

Other examples of that string might be:

Y-31,10,1N-5 (Here the arrays would be [31,10,1] and [5]
Y-1N-23,1,6 (Here the arrays would be [1] and [23,1,6]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First split the string into the two arrays string parts

```
    String str = "Y-1,2,3,4N-5,6,7,8";
    
    String str1 = str.substring(2, str.indexOf("N-")); // "1,2,3,4"
    String str2 = str.substring(str.indexOf("N-") + 2); // "5,6,7,8"
```

Then convert the array of strings to an array of ints using the `Integer.parseInt()`, simple java-8 solution with streams:

```
    int[] array1 = Arrays.stream(str1.split(",")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
    int[] array2 = Arrays.stream(str2.split(",")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```

> If you are in a version of java without streams, you need to use a simple for loop instead of the `Arrays.stream()`

Comment: I was struggling with how to create the substring when I did not have the exact index. Thank you! This worked perfectly! :)